# Client Object Model in WebPart

Tags: 2013, search-results

I am using the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search dll (Client Object Model) in a webpart because Microsoft.SharePoint.Search is obsolete.

When using the ClientContext.ExecuteQuery() method we get an "401 Unauthorized access error". To solve this issue I have used this piece of code:

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential cr = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");   
clientContext.Credentials = cr;
.....
SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery); 

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The same code works in a console application with no credentials but in a WebPart I get the 401 Unauthorized access error and the webpart needs to execute the query with the current logged user (I am in a Domain).

Any ideas?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.dll is obsolete?

Comment: Part of deprecating Sandboxed webparts.

Comment: Go to  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.search.query.aspx
Many classes are obsolete.
I am using Sharepoint 2013 standard and Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Do you issue a search query from the server? Then you should use Microsoft.SharePoint.Server.Search.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Managed Client Object Model will not work in a SharePoint context.  It's for "client" applications.  You could try the Silverlight Client Object Model or calling the Search web service in JavaScript.